# How to automatically change countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i got countdown script for one months so how i can do when countdown till zero then it should be automatically change to new countdown date for next months? without for me to manually change it every months myself.

its javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($){
        var newDate = new Date(2016, 4, 21);
        newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() + 18);
        $('#countdown-ex1').countdown({until: newDate});
    });
</script>
```

and Html

```
<div id="countdown-ex1" class="countdown countdown-large coming-soon divcenter bottommargin" style="max-width:700px;"></div>
```

Comment: How should your script know the exact end of the next count down? is it always the 21st day of the current month? and the 21st of the next month if today is the 22nd?

Comment: its random for next date we can add whatever date we like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should put in DB the desired dates. Create a function in module that gets the next date, sends that to controller, and in controller you should have something like this :

```
    $this->load->model('event_model');      
    $next = $this->event_model->getNext()[0]->next_date;    
    $next_date = explode("/",$next);

    $year = $next_date[0];
    $month = $next_date[1];
    $day = $next_date[2];

    $data['date_year'] = $year;     
    $data['date_month'] = $month;       
    $data['date_day'] = $day;
```

In your HTML you should put :

```
    var newDate = new Date(<?php echo $date_year; ?>, <?php echo $date_month; ?>, <?php echo $date_day; ?>);
```

For managing the dates you can delete manually in admin or whatever, or make some kind of script that checks actual date/time and deletes the records passed of the date.

Thats all, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The only line of code that is relavant to your issue is where the newDate variable is set:

```
var newDate = new Date(2016, 4, 21);
```

The should be set outside the function.  Then, when the function expires, you can set a new value and run the function again.  Also, the numbers within should be variables as well:

```
var yearIs=2016;
var monthIs=4;
var dayIs=12;
newDate = new Date(yearIs, monthIs, dayIs);
```

Comment: yeah i know but how i should add other date for automatically change to new date for next months and other months without me to set the date by manually as it should be update itself new date if countdown to zero.

Comment: I think your trouble is stemming from the fact that your current function runs on page load.  So it can't be called again.  You need to put the whole thing into its own function, and call THAT at page load.  Then, when it runs out, set a new date, and run it again.

Comment: its nothing wrong with my coding cos it work fine but i curious how i can make add other coding to make it auto change new date if older date run out then it should be update within new date self.

Answer (score 1):

With this example, your day of the month will be static, but the month will increment to make sure `newDate` is in the future.

You may set `startDate` date as you like - just don't set it too far in the past to save the browser some iterations.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var now = new Date();
  var startDate = new Date(2016, 3, 20);
  var newDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (newDate <= now) {
    // this will increment the date by 1 month until we're in the future
    newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() + 18);
  console.log(newDate);
  // the following check is only so we can run the code on SO without errors
  if ($('#countdown-ex1').length) {
    $('#countdown-ex1').countdown({
      until: newDate,
      expiryUrl: window.location // your URL here, to refresh the page
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And for the unlikely event that someone keeps the page open until the counter reaches zero, you can set `expiryUrl` so the countdown will refresh your page.

Comment: thanks but its not what i look for. as i want keep my coding cos it work fine but how i add other date and other date for in futrue date maybe next 2 week or 3 week cos they will be random date to set up. i curious how i can make my coding to auto change other date if it finished countdown to end then auto popup new date.